# How long have you run your Raspberry Pi since its inception in 2012

Tags: power

I would like to know how long can Raspberry pi be on without turning it off? I am looking for the maximum uptime. It's been 2.5 years since the Raspberry Pi was first launched and I am curious to know what the maximum up time anyone has achieved.

Is it possible to have it run a full year? So 24h a day, 7 days a week and 365 (or 366 :) days a year??

Comment: In my case, so far 4 months 24*7, only 3 reboots.

Comment: 71 days so far, since the last power outage. (So not that much to win a price...)

Comment: At times for me, continuous A/C power can be a roadblock to long uptime.  I've recently discovered that the unit can be powered from the 5V GPIO pin.  I have an Adafruit USB to TTL serial cable connected to my Pi for debugging and I found that I couldn't turn the Pi off until I disconnected the USB cable from the laptop I was using to monitor the serial console port.  My other big challenge is that I only have 256 MB or RAM and run out of RAM periodically.  I've added background services over time that use up all the RAM at times.

Comment: $ uptime
 11:20:54 up 316 days

Answer (score 2):

I had a quick scan of http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=49488&hilit=longest+uptime

563 days was the longest I noticed in the post.

The longest I've done is 35 days during a test.  I normally switch off overnight.

Comment: What happened after 563 days? did you just turn it off or did it die?

Comment: Oh, sorry, just realised you only did 35 and not the 563 - my bad :)

Comment: For all I know that one will be over 700 days now!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is certainly possible, as it happens I had to rewire a socket yesterday so I currently have an uptime of 1 day but it was getting on for 6 months prior to this. even then it was unplugged as I was reorganising my desk.

I'm not over-clocking it however, not sure if this would make any difference.